# Rails Admin routes inside config

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-admin

I'm using Rails Admin for my admin area. 
The sidebar panel should have some links to the instances of a model.
In rails_admin.rb I've tried something like:

```
RailsAdmin.config do |config|
  @navigation_links = Hash[*Conference.all.map {|conference| [conference.name, bindings[:view].main_app.show_path(model_name: 'conference', id: conference.id)]}.flatten]
  config.navigation_static_links = @navigation_links
end
```

However, here I do not have access to bindings. So, how can I get the url of an admin resource here? I cannot see it in the [documentation](https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/wiki/Using-RailsAdmin-routes)

Thanks

Comment: You want to add links to sidebar or static links?

Comment: @farhatmihalko I want to add links to the show of my conferences.

Comment: do you tried use static links?

Comment: could you bit more specific? I cannot see anything else in the documentation but https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/wiki/Navigation

Comment: In documentation - https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/wiki/Navigation there is section called `Static links`

Comment: In the last resort i can explain how you can solve your problem with `monkey patching`

Comment: That's exactly what I'm using :) It's in the code. Is really not possible without monkey patching? Anyways, I'm open to any suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

My answer probably not what you want to do, but it can be helpful.

I've checked `rails_admin.gem` and i found that there are two methods that responsible for rendering sidebar menu.

```
def main_navigation
  nodes_stack = RailsAdmin::Config.visible_models(controller: controller)
  node_model_names = nodes_stack.collect { |c| c.abstract_model.model_name }

  nodes_stack.group_by(&:navigation_label).collect do |navigation_label, nodes|
    nodes = nodes.select { |n| n.parent.nil? || !n.parent.to_s.in?(node_model_names) }
    li_stack = navigation nodes_stack, nodes

    label = navigation_label || t('admin.misc.navigation')

    %(<li class='dropdown-header'>#{capitalize_first_letter label}</li>#{li_stack}) if li_stack.present?
  end.join.html_safe
end
```

Method above responsible for getting list of models, especially:

```
nodes_stack = RailsAdmin::Config.visible_models(controller: controller)
```

Second method responsible for rendering item in the menu (aka `li`):

```
def navigation(nodes_stack, nodes, level = 0)
  nodes.collect do |node|
    model_param = node.abstract_model.to_param
    url         = url_for(action: :index, controller: 'rails_admin/main', model_name: model_param)
    level_class = " nav-level-#{level}" if level > 0
    nav_icon = node.navigation_icon ? %(<i class="#{node.navigation_icon}"></i>).html_safe : ''
    li = content_tag :li, data: {model: model_param} do
      link_to nav_icon + capitalize_first_letter(node.label_plural), url, class: "pjax#{level_class}"
    end
    li + navigation(nodes_stack, nodes_stack.select { |n| n.parent.to_s == node.abstract_model.model_name }, level + 1)
  end.join.html_safe
end
```

So you can `patch` this methods to get what you need.

```
module RailsAdmin
  module ApplicationHelper
    def main_navigation
      # your code
    end
  end
end
```

[rails_admin.gem module](https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/blob/master/app/helpers/rails_admin/application_helper.rb#L73)

P.S. I love what you can read from [rails doctrine](http://rubyonrails.org/doctrine) about `monkey patching`:

> This power has frequently been derided as simply too much for mere
>   mortal programmers to handle.

Comment: Not really what I need. Even if I monkey patch main_navigation, I don't want to show all the instances of all models. I want to show the instances of my model Conference. Thanks for your time anyways :)

Comment: @dioshari by saying `patch` i mean that you can add code, which will show what you need (instances of Conference)

Comment: @dioshari what about dynamically adding by using javascript?